# How can I make mono accept a PE32 DLL on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, mingw-w64

I'm trying to build a native win32 app on Linux host using `mcs` mono compiler.

I have a library (`CoolLib.dll`) that has the following line

```cs
[global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("MyLib.dll", EntryPoint="...")]
```

It's compiled  using `mcs` and thus has the following format

```
$ file CoolLib.dll
PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
```

Now, `MyLib.dll` is also mine and I compiled on the same host with `mingw-g++`.

```
$ file MyLib.dll
MyLib.dll: PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

I then compile my hello world executable that references `CoolLib.dll`...

```
mcs /reference:CoolLib.dll /out:main.exe /target:x64 main.cs
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono main.exe
```

...but it blows up with `System.DllNotFoundException`.

**Though what I don't understand is why  it complains about  `MyLib.dll` not being an ELF**

```
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/bindings_test/MyLib.dll': '/bindings_test/MyLib.dll: invalid ELF header'.
```

after all, it's supposed to be a win32 library. Why does mono expect it to be an ELF?

Comment: Libraries compiled for Windows are in PE32 envelope which are not consumed by Linux apps (Mono or not). You have to compile them as ELF format (aka Linux executable, usually `.so` files). Mono only allows you to load such on Linux. BTW, you really should migrate to .NET Core, as Mono is going away.

Comment: I see. What puzzled me though was that CoolLib (built with mono) was a PE32 library, and yet, mono had no trouble consuming it. I guess that it's because CoolLib was built by  `mcs` and that made it somewhat *different*?

Comment: All managed assemblies for Mono are in PE32 envelope, but they only contains managed MSIL, not native code for Windows. This can be hard for beginners to digest, but native vs. managed is so important and you cannot miss this part.

Comment: @LexLi ah. I see. IMO you should upgrade your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the comments.

A few facts you need to keep in mind are,

- Linux/macOS native executable is in ELF format (.so and others)
- Windows native executable is in PE32 format (.dll and .exe)
- .NET assemblies (managed) are in PE32 format (.dll and .exe)

Microsoft decided to reuse the same file extensions and file format for managed bits, so many people like you won't easily notice the big changes until moving to another operating system.

So to answer your question, if you have some C/C++ dependencies to wrap over on Linux, then they must be recompiled in ELF format using the native C/C++ compiler. Then your .NET Core/Mono apps can use PInvoke to consume them. You cannot use those native dependencies in PE32 format, because Linux won't recognize what's that.

Answer (score 0):

The library generated with `mcs` is for target `Intel 80386` while the one built with `mingw-g++` is for target `x86-64`.

You can't mix platforms. Build everything for either 32-bit or 64-bit Windows.

For example use a 32-bit version by using a 32-bit version of MinGW-w64 or use the `-m32` flag if you have a MinGW-w64 version that supports both targets.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if  targeting the same platform, the issue is  the same. I've updated the OP.

Comment: Are you using an `mcs` on Linux that is actually targetting Linux x64 instead of Windows? In that case your target CPU may be the same, but not the OS, so the target may different. A Linux target could explain why ELF is used.